# Why is nitronium ion an electrophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronic-configuration

I have learnt that the species which have vacant orbital(s) are called electrophiles. But in this case, the nitrogen has a complete octet. The positively charged nitrogen ion has a valency of 4, of which 2-2 are satisfied by each oxygen atoms.

Still, $\ce{NO2+}$ acts as a nucleophile. Why?

Comment: It has empty π* orbitals that are low in energy. The "low-energy" bit is important: *everything* has vacant orbitals, but not everything can be an electrophile.

Comment: Compare to the isoelectronic CO2.